# Transfer/Claim In-App Purchase to/on Another Device

Tags: fallout-shelter

Can someone who purchased an item (specifically a single or a pack of Mr. Handy's) on one device "revive" or "re-use" them on another device, without making a second purchase on the second device?

This is assuming both devices are connected to the same app store account (specifically Google Play).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

The in-app purchases are tied to the specific saved game and that is it. If that saved game gets lost for whatever reason those purchases are gone. There is currently no way to move them from device to device or even vault to vault.